# Reading a CSV in Python - columns not at start of file

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to adjust a script that previously took in a CSV file where the columns were at the start of a file, however now the CSV it reads has changed so that there is a load of spiel before the column headers are given.

Is there a way using DictReader (or even any other method) to skip down to where the columns are (line 15) and use these?
Currently I'm using the below code, but it will always take the first line in the file.

```
f = open(fileName)
reader = csv.DictReader(f)
lineU = 0
for underlyer in reader:
    lineU = lineU + 1
    if(lineU == 6):
       #start the code
```

Appreciate any help given.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the 15 lines from `f` first, before passing it to the `DictReader`.

Answer (score 0):

The `csv.reader` will iterate over the file, so you can basically read those lines using `file.readline()`before starting using the reader, so that they don't appear to the reader.